# How is wet cellulose insulation usually blown into walls?

Tags: insulation, construction, new-home

I'm dried-in on new construction on my own house and plan to DIY the insulation as I have done many times. Not looking forward to stapling it up. I see companies offering a wall cellulose solution where they spray a wet cellulose on unfinished walls, between and over studs, scrape off excess onto the floor with a squeegee, wait for it to dry and then wall it up. No one rents or sells a machine pre-configured with a sprayer / mister that I can find.

Is this a rig it up yourself kind of thing and if so, how is it commonly done? Is it going to be a big experiment that won't save me time before I finally get it right (right amount of water and dispersal pattern)? I did find a local company that offers the service, but feel bad asking the "how do you do it" kind of question when I plan on doing insulation myself.

Comment: I don't have any direct experience with this, but I can tell you that when I looked into this for a home construction project of my own, I found a lot of anecdotes about improperly-trained people spraying it wrong. The main problem seems to be over-wetting the cellulose before spraying. The most common consequence was a significant delay in the overall project, as a result of having to wait much longer for it to dry enough to drywall. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a local contractor who provided the service, and so wound up with dry, "dense-pack" installation.

Comment: Note that the consequence of doing wet cellulose wrong is not nearly as bad as if spray-foam is done wrong. :) BTW, as far as asking your local contractor for advice goes...doesn't hurt to try. Their choice whether to help or not; you can't impose on them, since they don't have to answer any questions they don't want to. As long as you're up-front about it, it seems fine. And what do they get out of it? Well, if and when you decide it's more trouble than it's worth to do it yourself, they'd presumably be first in line for the job. A gamble on their part, but the cost to them is pretty minimal.

Comment: My son just finished a super insulated, energy efficient house and part of the insulation was spray foam.  While I realize this is a DIY forum, that's something that needs to be left to the pros. He negotiated with the insulation company to get the R value he needed and they applied the spray foam to the desired depth.   Not an easy task.  Again, I'd love to help in this DIY forum, but in this case, you need to get a pro.

Comment: I fitted 30cm of insulation to our build - it came in bats of 1.3m by 80cm and was 10 or 20 thick to give 30cm. This was a wood fibre based insulation which does not irritate the skin like some, easy to cut to shape and fit. Builder thought he had 4 weeks to go do another job - we wanted him back on site in 10 days, he could not believe we were so quick, he now uses that insulation as a standard part of his builds, his workers love it.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson, cellulose isn't foam. It's much more safe and forgiving as it doesn't expand or stick to everything like glue.

Comment: Have you considered a mesh bib system and blown fiberglass?

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure how that applies to this question...

Comment: @isherwood  Thanks for the comment.  Yes I realized they are different products, but didn't make that obvious in my comment. I just wanted to offer an alternative to the cellulose.   I agree with you, that spray form dries up pretty hard and coats everything.While supposedly very energy efficient, I'm not a fan of it bc it just encapsulates everything.

Comment: @FreeMan just suggesting an option - it’s insulation so it is « sort » of relevant.